# Get rid of "Bluetooth OFF" icon on windows 8

Tags: windows, bluetooth, notifications

Windows 8 is one hell of a wonderful operating system.
One of its particularly splendid features is presenting information on turned off devices. In particular, when the bluetooth radio is turned off, it presents the user with a high-contrast blue and red icon. Clicking on it, informs the poor soul of the fact that the bluetooth is off.

[image: Pop-up message that appears by clicking on the icon]

I am curious if there is a way to get rid of this icon. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Bluetooth/Notification Area Icon` only seems to affect the active bluetooth icon (regular white and blue state). Hiding all notification icons is also not an option.

Just as a note, I am running this on Lenovo t430 with the recent Bluetooth driver update (Broadcom v12.0.0.7030).

Please help me get rid of this pesky eye-sore of an icon.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Open msconfig/task manager and turn it off in autostart.